# Docker port forwarding between container and host

Tags: docker

I'm new at docker and I'm trying to test some things. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) I saw that we can map ports between the container and the host.

So I pull the `mariadb` repo and run a container like this

```
$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3307:3306 --name mdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker -d mariadb
```

> This would bind port 3306 inside the container to port 3307 on the localhost or 127.0.0.1 interface on the host machine.

And It creates the container, I check it with `$ docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
f7d30562194c        mariadb             "/docker-entrypoint.   About an hour ago   Up 6 minutes        127.0.0.1:3307->3306/tcp   mdb
```

But when I telnet to the port, I got nothing

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3307
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I'm doing this becouse I've got a `mysql` running in the 3306 port, and I don't want to mess with that. I try switching the orders on the `-p` option and also nothing on the telnet. Can you help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

(Also I'm running over `boot2docker` on OSX `10.9.5`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boot2docker, that means you need to forward that port at the VM level itself:

```
VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 "name,tcp,127.0.0.1,3307,,3307"
```

See:

- [issues/4007:  Port forwarding when using boot2docker on OSX](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4007)
- [Boot2docker workarounds: Port forwarding](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md#port-forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that if you're using `boot2docker`, you need to address localhost on the boot2docker VM, not the Mac.

To make the problem clear, this should work:

```
$ boot2docker ssh
...
$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3307:3306 --name mdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker -d mariadb
...
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3307
```

But obviously you don't want to ssh into the VM each time. So I would just replace 127.0.0.1 with the IP of the boot2docker VM and you're done:

```
$ telnet $(boot2docker ip) 3307
```