# How let gogs support ssh

Tags: docker, gogs

After install gogs, i want to let gogs support ssh. In the insall web page, i filled the `Run User` with `git`. when I use ssh to git clone, gogs need me to input `git@xxx's password`. But I don't know the `git@xxx's password`. What should I do to solve this problem? I use the docker `codeskyblue/docker-gogs` to run my container. And I also depend on the `README` to set `SSH_PORT = 10022`.

Answer (score 0):

From [issues/1292](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/1292), you need to:

- check ssh with `ssh -p 10022 git@xyz`,
- make sure your `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` public key is in your gogs account, not on the system's authorized_keys,
- check if [a `$HOME/.ssh/config` file could help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1558735/6309).

Note that if you are using docker through a VM with boot2docker, you also [need to add a port forwarding rule on that VM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31509414/6309).