# Can't access the dockerized app launched from the command line from outside

Tags: ruby, docker

I have built a Docker image with Ruby and some gems as a starting point for my projects. Its available at: `jikkujose/trial`. I am trying this out in a Mac, using the default docker-toolbox.

I am trying to use it to host a single file app. I am launching it as follows:

`docker run -itdP -v .:/app jikkujose/docker`

The current directory contains a file `app.rb` with the following:

```
require 'sinatra'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :bind, "0.0.0.0"

  get '/' do
    'This is interesting :)'
  end
end

App.run!
```

I am able to *attach* to the container to launch the app. And the following is seen when I do: `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                     NAMES
92498cafd985        jikkujose/trial     "/bin/bash"              18 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds                 0.0.0.0:32780->4567/tcp   boring_meitner
```

And I am trying to access the application using the ip obtained via `docker-machine ip default`.

While trying to access the the app using `curl`, I am getting the following:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 32780: Connection refused
```

Comment: Just to be sure, what is the output of `docker-machine ip default`?

Comment: Please also provide your `Dockerfile` as it is not available on docker-hub.

Comment: @michaelbahr I didn't build it using a Dockerfile. I built using commits. And the IP is the same: `192.168.99.100`

Comment: Is the problem because there is no server running when the container gets launched?

Comment: With your container running, what happens if you do a `docker exec <container id> curl http://localhost:4567`

Comment: `curl` wasn't there in it; I just installed it and tried it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 32780: Connection refused
```

That should mean there is no listener, or, since a `docker exec <container id> curl http://localhost:4567` does work, that the listener does not accept queries from broadcast, only from localhost...

Your [entrypoint and cmd are](https://github.com/JikkuJose/violet/blob/d3d01426bc98aaf6eef32da19635e13f75a469a3/Dockerfile#L8-L9):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby"]
CMD ["/app/app.rb"]
```

Check if others mean to launch a sinatra app would work better with a docker environment: for instance "[Dockerizing simple Sinatra app using docker and fig](https://www.computersnyou.com/4267/dockerizing-simple-sinatra-app-using-docker-fig/)" (fig is the old name of docker compose)

Before that, check if the mapped port is [forwarded at the VirtualBox level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31509414/6309):

```
VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 "name,tcp,127.0.0.1,32780,,32780"
```

Comment: I have already done that; I am doing a `curl` on the exposed port itself and also accessing using the `IP` of the `VM`.

Comment: @JikkuJose my point is, when you use -P , you don't know which port is actually used: what a docker ps -a returns?

Comment: I know that, I have already provided the output of `docker ps -a` and I am using the randomly chosen port: `32780 `. (You can scroll that output included with the question to see it)

Comment: @JikkuJose Right. I have rewritten the answer to propose an alternative

Comment: I didn't build it using a `Dockerfile`. Thanks for the link, I had reviewed it earlier. My goal isn't running Sinatra; its just to access an exposed port and running a server in the container launched via command line than the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @JikkuJose I understand, could it be that the mapped port is not declared in the VirtualBox network setting? I have edited the answer for more (with a link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/31509414/6309)

Comment: I am not using `boot2docker`; but the latest `docker-toolbox`. Also, the same ports work on another image that was downloaded. It seems to me that something subtle is missing in the way I run it.

Comment: @JikkuJose same issue: toolbox or boot2docker: you need to forward the port on the VM side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92572/discussion-between-jikku-jose-and-vonc).

Comment: can you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667467/cant-access-dockers-exposed-port-in-ubuntu