# Unable to view rails app running in docker container from browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am running a rails app in a docker container and after executing `docker-compose up` I look in the browser and see `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I have tried port forwarding via `docker run -p 3000:3000 docker_app` and still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: What URL do you try and access in the browser ?

Comment: What's system are you running docker? if you are using Mac, it is not '127.0.0.1', it should be the real container ip which you can obtain by issuing commane 'docker-machine ip default`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boot2docker or docker toolbox or docker machine (on an OS different from Linux, meaning using a VirtualBox VM), that means you need to forward that port at the VM level itself:

```
VBoxManage controlvm boot2docker-vm natpf1 "name,tcp,,3000,,3000"
```

The VM needs to forward that port from localhost to itself, before the docker port mapping can act.
I had a similar case [with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33170641/6309).

Then try to access `http://$(docker-machine ip default):3000`, as [mainframer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4258008/mainframer) comments.

Comment: I used docker-machine to create the host vm.

Comment: @GrahamJackson toolbox, machine, ... if you are using a VM, you need port forwarding.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you Von!

Comment: I exposed port 3000 on the host machine, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @GrahamJackson I have changed the VBoxManage command, and integrated mainframer's comment.