# Multiple FROMs - what it means

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image, which requires both a Neo4j database and Node.js to run.

My first approach was to declare a base image for my image, containing Neo4j. The reference docs do not define "base image" in any helpful manner:

> Base image:
> An image that has no parent is a base image

from which I read that I may only have a base image if that image has no base image itself.

But what is a base image? Does it mean, if I declare neo4j/neo4j in a FROM directive, that when my image is run the neo database will automatically run and be available within the container on port 7474?

Reading the [Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) I see:

> FROM can appear multiple times within a single Dockerfile in order to create multiple images. Simply make a note of the last image ID output by the commit before each new FROM command.

Do I want to create multiple images? It would seem what I want is to have a single image that contains the contents of other images e.g. neo4j and node.js.

I've found no directive to declare dependencies in the reference manual. Are there no dependencies like in RPM where in order to run my image the calling context must first install the images it needs?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

As of May 2017, multiple `FROM`s can be used in a single Dockerfile.
See "[Builder pattern vs. Multi-stage builds in Docker](http://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/)" (by [Alex Ellis](https://twitter.com/alexellisuk)) and [PR 31257](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31257) by [Tõnis Tiigi](https://github.com/tonistiigi).

> The general syntax involves adding `FROM` additional times within your Dockerfile - whichever is the last `FROM` statement is the final base image. To copy artifacts and outputs from intermediate images use `COPY --from=<base_image_number>`.

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go    .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app    .
CMD ["./app"]
```

The result would be two images, one for building, one with just the resulting app (much, *much* smaller)

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

multi               latest              bcbbf69a9b59        6 minutes ago       10.3MB  
golang              1.7.3               ef15416724f6        4 months ago        672MB
```

---

> what is a base image?

A set of files, plus [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose)'d ports, [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd).
You can add files and build a new image based on that base image, with a new `Dockerfile` starting with a `FROM` directive: the image mentioned after `FROM` is "the base image" for your new image.

> does it mean that if I declare `neo4j/neo4j` in a `FROM` directive, that when my image is run the neo database will automatically run and be available within the container on port 7474?

Only if you don't overwrite `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`.
But the image in itself is enough: you would use a `FROM neo4j/neo4j` if you had to add files related to `neo4j` for your particular usage of `neo4j`.

---

2018: With the introduction of the [`--target` option in `docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/build/#target), you gain even more control over multi-stage builds.
This feature enables you to select which `FROM` statement in your Dockerfile you wish to build, allowing for more modular and efficient Docker images. This is especially useful in scenarios where you might want to:

1. **Build Only the Dependencies**: Create an image that only contains the dependencies of your project. This can be useful for caching purposes or for environments where you only need to run tests or static analysis tools.
2. **Separate Build and Runtime Environments**: Compile or build your application in a full-featured build environment but create a smaller, more secure image for deployment that only includes the runtime environment and the compiled application.
3. **Create Images for Different Environments**: Have different stages for development, testing, and production environments, each tailored with the specific tools and configurations needed for those environments.

#### Example Using `--target`

Given a Dockerfile with multiple stages named `builder`, `tester`, and `deployer`, you can build up to the `tester` stage using the `--target` option like so:

```bash
docker build --target tester -t myapp-test .
```

This command tells Docker to stop building after the `tester` stage has been completed, thus creating an image that includes everything from the base image up to the `tester` stage, but excluding anything from `deployer` stage and beyond.

#### Dockerfile Example with `--target` Usage

```
# Builder stage
FROM golang:1.7.3 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/example/project/
# Assume app.go exists and has a function
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

# Tester stage
FROM builder as tester
COPY . .
RUN go test ./...

# Deployer stage
FROM alpine:latest as deployer
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/example/project/app /app
CMD ["/app"]
```

Using the `--target` option with this Dockerfile allows for flexibility in building images tailored for specific steps of the development lifecycle.

As illustrated in "[Building a multi-stage Dockerfile with --target flag builds all stages instead of just the specified one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51253987/6309)", this works well with BuildKit, which is [now (2023+) the default builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76929307/6309).
From that page, you have [Igor Kulebyakin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4006768/igor-kulebyakin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843162/6309):

> If one wants to make sure that the current target stage is force re-built even if it has already been cached without rebuilding the previous dependent stages, once can use the docker build [`--no-cache-filter` flag](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/buildx/build/#no-cache-filter).
>
> An example, given you have a multi-stage Dockerfile with a 'test' stage, would be:
>
> ```
> docker build --no-cache-filter test --target test --tag your-image-name:version .
> ```

Comment: @rainabba Agreed. Legacy monoliths won't be migrated easily. Interesting reads: https://martinfowler.com/articles/break-monolith-into-microservices.html, https://threedots.tech/post/microservices-or-monolith-its-detail/, https://hackernoon.com/aws-lambda-should-you-have-few-monolithic-functions-or-many-single-purposed-functions-8c3872d4338f

Comment: If I have multiple `FROM` statements in one Dockerfile, for some reason it skips the first and only executes the second one.

Comment: @pfincent I would be interested to see a separate question, with an example and the version of Docker and OS you are using.

Comment: Note that this answer has been written before the [target](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/build/#target) option has been added to ` docker build`, with this feature you can pick which `FROM` statement you want to build in a single `Dockerfile`, where it will only build all stages required to build this

Comment: @Ferrybig Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have edited my 2015 answer to include this option.

Answer (score 99):

Let me summarize my understanding of the question and the answer, hoping that it will be useful to others.

**Question**: Let’s say I have three images, *apple*, *banana* and *orange*. Can I have a Dockerfile that has `FROM apple`, `FROM banana` and `FROM orange` that will tell docker to magically merge all three applications into a **single** image (containing the three individual applications) which I could call *smoothie*?

**Answer**: *No, you can't*. If you do that, you will end up with four images, the three fruit images you pulled, plus the new image based on the last `FROM` image. If, for example, `FROM orange` was  the last statement in the Dockerfile without anything added, the *smoothie* image would just be a clone of the *orange* image.

##### Why Are They Not Merged? I Really Want It

A typical docker image will contain almost everything the application needs to run (leaving out the kernel) which usually means that they’re built from a base image for their chosen operating system and a particular version or distribution.

Merging images successfully without considering all possible distributions, file systems, libraries and applications, is not something Docker, understandably, wants to do. Instead, developers are expected to embrace the [microservices paradigm](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/why-should-we-use-microservices-and-containers/), running [multiple containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) that talk to each other as needed.

##### What’s the Alternative?

One possible use case for image merging would be to mix and match Linux distributions with our desired applications, for example, Ubuntu and Node.js. This is **not** the solution:

```
FROM ubuntu
FROM node
```

If we don’t want to stick with the Linux distribution chosen by our application image, we can start with our chosen distribution and use the package manager to install the applications instead, e.g.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install package1 &&\
    apt-get install package2
```

But you probably knew that already. Often times there isn’t a [snap](https://snapcraft.io) or package available in the chosen distribution, or it’s not the desired  version, or it doesn't work well in a docker container out of the box, which was the motivation for wanting to use an image. I’m just confirming that, as far as I know, the only option is to do it the long way, if you really want to follow a monolithic approach.

In the case of *Node.js* for example, you might want to [manually install](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation) the latest version, since `apt` provides an ancient one, and `snap` does not come with the Ubuntu image. For *neo4j* we might have to [download](https://neo4j.com/download/) the package and manually add it to the image, according to the documentation and the license.

One strategy, if size does not matter, is to start with the base image that would be hardest to install manually, and add the rest on top.

##### When To Use Multiple FROM Directives

There is also the option to use multiple `FROM` statements and manually copy stuff between build stages or into your final one. In other words, you can manually merge images, if you know what you're doing. As per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> Optionally a name can be given to a new build stage by adding `AS name`
> to the `FROM` instruction. The name can be used in subsequent `FROM` and
> `COPY --from=<name>` instructions to refer to the image built in this
> stage.

Personally, I’d only be comfortable using this merge approach with my own images or by following documentation from the application vendor, but it’s there if you need it or you're just feeling lucky.

A better application of this approach though, would be when we actually do want to use a temporary container from a *different image*, for building or doing something and discard it after copying the desired output.

###### Example

I wanted a lean image with `gpgv` only, and based on this [Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722234/212177), I installed the whole `gpg` with `yum` and then copied only the binaries required, to the final image:

```
FROM docker.io/photon:latest AS builder
RUN yum install gnupg -y

FROM docker.io/photon:latest
COPY --from=builder /usr/bin/gpgv /usr/bin/
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.20 /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 /usr/lib/
```

The rest of the `Dockerfile` continues as usual.

Comment: I feel like Docker is missing a pretty key feature: being able to import/extend Dockerfiles, not only Docker images. It seems like what I would want to do, in almost all cases, would be to build an image by combining two Dockerfiles in an intelligent way: basically, append all the `ENV` and `RUN` directives from one Dockerfile to the end of another one, perhaps after checking that their `FROM`s are "similar" (same distro). If this sounds too wishy-washy to you, consider that many people are probably already doing it, just by copy-and-pasting instead of it being built into the tool.

Comment: See this 10-year discussion: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/735

Comment: Agree that it would be nice to have a feature to support a "merge" of some sort or at least attempt it. I initially thought that `FROM` might be a way to do it and realized that it wasn't, so I wrote this answer to explain the situation and provide alternatives. If you have other solutions, we'd like to hear them.

Answer (score 30):

The first answer is too complex, historic, and uninformative for my tastes.

---

It's actually rather simple. Docker provides for a functionality called [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) the basic idea here is to,

- Free you from having to manually remove what you don't want, by forcing you to allowlist what you do want,
- Free resources that would otherwise be taken up because of Docker's implementation.

Let's start with the first. Very often with something like Debian you'll see.

```
RUN apt-get update \ 
  && apt-get dist-upgrade \
  && apt-get install <whatever> \
  && apt-get clean
```

We can explain all of this in terms of the above. The above command is chained together so it represents a single change with no intermediate Images required. If it was written like this,

```
RUN apt-get update ;
RUN apt-get dist-upgrade;
RUN apt-get install <whatever>;
RUN apt-get clean;
```

It would result in 3 more temporary intermediate Images. Having it reduced to one image, there is one remaining problem: `apt-get clean` doesn't clean up artifacts used in the install. If a Debian maintainer includes in his install a script that modifies the system that modification will also be present in the final solution (see something like `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` for an example of that).

By using a multi-stage build you get all the benefits of a single changed action, but it will require you to manually allowlist and copy over files that were introduced in the temporary image using the `COPY --from` syntax documented here. Moreover, it's a great solution where there is no alternative (like an `apt-get clean`), and you would otherwise have lots of un-needed files in your final image.

See also

- [Multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)
- [COPY syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Comment: thanks but I don't see how you're addressing my issue.  to me, FROM is an inheritance mechanism and having multiple directives means I can inherit from multiple parents.  in your answer you make no mention of FROM or the concept of taking advantage of the packaging of software by others

Comment: Perhaps that's the confusion. `FROM` is principally a namespace declaration. The qualifier there is more like an extension than inheritance. You can declare multiple namespaces. And each of those namespaces can extend one other namespace. @ekkis If the other answer works for you, then by all means stick with it.

Comment: @ekkis You do not inherit from the first image using `FROM`, instead, at least [how I understood it](https://superuser.com/questions/1635191/dockerfile-how-to-create-a-new-image-from-the-last-layer-of-another-image), you copy the directories of your choice from images of your choice. What I do not know is how I would find out the image IDs of each line which this answer mentions, but that should be found on the net. Anyway, the [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) link is the same thing as the first answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is probably one of the most fundamental use cases of using multiple `FROM`s, aka, multi stage builds.

I want want one dockerfile, and I want to change one word and depending on what I set that word to, I get different images depending on whether I want to run, Dev or Publish the application!

**Run** - I just want to run the app

**Dev** - I want to edit the code and run the app

**Publish** - Run the app in production

Lets suppose we're working in the dotnet environment. Heres one single Dockerfile. Without multi stage build, there would be multiple files (builder pattern)

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj", "ConsoleApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ConsoleApp1"
RUN dotnet build "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

Want to run the app? Leave `FROM base AS final` as it currently is in the dockerfile above.

Want to dev the source code in the container? Change the same line to `FROM build AS final`

Want to release into prod? Change the same line to `FROM publish AS final`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the OP, that this feature is useful for docker! Here is a different view into the same problem:

If you had multiple FROMs (or a "FROM" and multiple "MERGE"'s, for example) then you can use the docker registry versioning system for the base docker image AND other container elements, and that is the win here: I have third party development tools which do not exist in .deb format, so these tools must be installed by un-taring a tball and is HUGE, so caching on the docker host will be important but versioning/change control of the image is equally important. I (think I) can simply use "RUN git ....", and docker will deal with the caching of the new layer for me, which is what I want; because another container will have the same base image but a different set of HUGE third party tools, so the caching of the base image and the tools image is really important (the 3rd party tools tar can be as big as the base image of say ubuntu so caching of these is really important too). The (suggested) feature just allows all these elements to be managed in a central repo. versioning system.

Said a different way, why do we use FROM at all? If I were to simply git clone an ubuntu image using the RUN command for my "base image/layer", this would create a new layer and docker would cache this anyway...so is there any difference/advantage in using FROM, other than it uses dockers internal versioning system/syntax?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31859976)