# How install java to ubuntu on docker?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, docker

I tried use docker. I install tool docker and run. I dovnload ubuntu image and run on docker. I make all by this [link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)

For install ubuntu I used `docker run -it ubuntu bash`

After that I run this ubuntu  `docker run -i -t ubuntu:latest /bin/bash`

After start I placed `root@9bca9a2a537d:/#`

Now I want install java and start some app on this java.

I tried install java `root@cf50a6fdfc10:/# apt-get install default-jre`

When this installed i try run this command `java -version` and I see

```
root@2e62f448f783:/# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

after that i exit from ubuntu

```
root@2e62f448f783:/# exit
```

and run again. And when ubuntu started i try

```
root@20cefe55e2eb:/# java -version
bash: java: command not found
```

How can I install java or start this java version?

Comment: Are you trying to use a Docker container like a regular virtual machine? That's not really how it works. You should write a `Dockerfile` that starts with the base Ubuntu image you want, installs Java, copies across your app and sets it up to run.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK. let's say I've created a file docker. Then what I do with it? I imagine this is so - I run docker. install all need Programs  (java, db, some utilites). test how it works. If all is well then I create an image. then I install that image in another docker on another computer.

Comment: In Docker data are not persist in the container unless it is associated with a volume that is mapped to a file system.

Comment: then I do not understand how it works

Comment: Well have you considered reading the [introductory tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/) or the docs (e.g. [`Dockerfile` reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/))? You supply a list of steps that tells Docker how to build the container you want, then it's easily repeatable, rather than having to set it up in a running machine. See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/flash/blob/master/Dockerfile, from one of my own projects.

Answer (score 18):

As [paulscott56](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38506907/4277724) said, you can add those lines in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get -y install default-jre-headless && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/pataquets/default-jre-headless/~/dockerfile/

Comment: In some images you might need to create directory `mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1`

Answer (score 4):

why not use the official Java images, or the alpine Java, and just put in your Dockerfile

`FROM java`

or

`FROM anapsix/alpine-java`

? You have a functional Java installed and can do whatever you want.

See

http://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=java&starCount=0

for some Java from the docker hub

You should read the good links provided by jonrsharpe

Comment: What if I'm already using a different base image, and need to add java to it? It's not possible to have two base images.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322103/multiple-froms-what-it-means and VonC excellent answer

Answer (score 1):

The container is a single contained entity. All changes that you make to it are essentially lost when you quit and restart it. There are 2 solutions to his though:

1. Do it properly, and add java to a RUN apt-get line in your Dockerfile,
   OR
2. (Bad bad bad) Add it and hope your host never goes down.

Depending on what you want (Ubuntu or a container to run a Java app), you should either use the method in 1. or create a new Dockerfile that grabs FROM Java8 base image.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to commit the updated Image after installing Ubuntu.Try the following after installing java on the running container :

```
docker ps -l #get current container ID , let's sat it is "container_id"
```

Then :

```
docker commit container_id ubuntu_with_java
```

It would create a new Image with name "ubuntu_with_java" .

Comment: [*"Generally, it is better to use Dockerfiles to manage your images in a documented and maintainable way.*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Dockerfile if you want to have JDK on my images, or you can have a multi-stage build with java with ubuntu.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```