# Dockerfile with multiple images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What I want to build, without Docker, would look like this:

- AWS EC2 Debian OS where I can install:
- Python 3
- Anaconda
- Run python scripts that will create new files as output
- SSH into it so that I can explore the new files created

I am starting to use Docker an my first approach was to build everything into a Dockerfile but I don't know how to add multiple FROM so that I can install the official docker image of Debian, Python3 and Anaconda.

In addition, with this approach is it possible to get into the container and explore the files that have been created?

Comment: Found this question, which can answer your question
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322103/multiple-froms-what-it-means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322103/multiple-froms-what-it-means)

Comment: Do you really need to install SSH when you can `docker exec`? See the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: with multiple FROM, only last FROM would be your base image.