# Docker run multiple image with single Dockerfile?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, tomcat8

I am trying to test and use docker for my environment. Here is my Dockerfile
When I access the tomcat (`http://localhost:8080`), I get the problem `This site can’t be reached`.

Note => For window, I use `http://192.168.99.100:8080/`.

Build

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker-spring-rest .
```

Run

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 3306:3306 docker-spring-rest
```

Dockerfile

```
#Prat-1 tomcat
FROM tomcat:8.5.35
COPY ./target/spring-rest.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080

#Prat-1 tomcat
FROM mysql:5.5
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE spring-rest
COPY ./DB.SQL /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

One strange thing is, If I setup only `Part-1 tomcat` without `mysql`, I can access `http://192.168.99.100:8080/` or my application `http://192.168.99.100:8080/spring-rest`
Is there any missing in my file?

Googling => I checked this [tomcat-mysql](https://hub.docker.com/r/aallam/tomcat-mysql/~/dockerfile/) reference. Why they use `apt-get` to install because of docker already have multiple images?
Can I use multiple `FROM` like `FROM tomcat, FROM mysql, FROM xxx` in single `Dockerfile`?

Comment: If you have multiple containers you should use docker-compose for that. Maybe they use apt-get because they install it into current image machine?

Comment: inspiration https://github.com/twogg-git/docker-compose-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322103/multiple-froms-what-it-means : The general syntax involves adding FROM additional times within your Dockerfile - whichever is the last FROM statement is the final base image. To copy artifacts and outputs from intermediate images use COPY --from=<base_image_number>.

Answer (score 2):

The key question is here: "Can I use multiple `FROM` ... in a single Dockerfile".

If you do that, you are using a new docker feature called [multistage-build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds). This feature allows you to build an image in multiple stages, where each `FROM` starts from a fresh base layer, *discarding everything you did before*.

This is not what you intent to do, because when you do `FROM mysql:5.5` you loose the entire tomcat part from above that line.

You could build a docker image containing tomcat and mysql (using only one `FROM`) instruction, but I would advised against it.
[Docker images are supposed to deal with one concern only](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#decouple-applications).

So indeed the best solution would be to create two Docker images (2 Dockerfiles), one for tomcat, one for mysql and then use docker-compose to run the two as a composite.

Comment: In addition to this (for the OP): Also note that the tomcat-mysql image is BAD practice as an image since it also violates the single concern as mentioned by @fab

Comment: @fab, one xxx for one Dockerfile? Is is possible to run all of them at the same time using single shell or what ever? Now I will check your reference `multistage-build`

Comment: Yes, the tool to run all of them at the same time is [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). In your shell you simply type `docker-compose up` and you need to provide a docker-compose.yaml file in the current directory which references your tomcat & mysql image.