# apt-get not found in Docker

Tags: dockerfile

I've got this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
FROM ubuntu
FROM alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

and it's throwing error saying `/bin/sh: apt-get: not found`.
I thought `apt-get` package is part of Ubuntu image that I'm pulling on the
second line but yet it's giving me this error.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You can only use a single base image, not three.

Answer (score 11):

as tkausl said: you can only use one base image (one FROM).

alpine's package manager is `apk` not `apt-get`. you have to use apk to install packages. however, pip is already available.

that Dockerfile should work:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: One question where should I keep the requirement.txt file. can you tell me that? Because when I keep the requirement.txt file in the same place where docker file is there it displays ' no such file or directory'

Comment: You have to copy the requirements.txt into the container before running the pip install...

Answer (score 5):

**`apt-get`** does not work because the active Linux distribution is `alpine`, and it does not have the **`apt-get`** command.

You can fix it using **`apk`** command.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

most probbly the image you're using is Alpine, 
so you can't use apt-get 
you can use Ubuntu's package manager.

you can use 
`apk update` and `apk add`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `FROM` lines can be used in a single `Dockerfile`.

See [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322103/multiple-froms-what-it-means) and [Multi stage tutorial](https://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/)

The use of Python Alpine, plus Ubuntu, plus Ubuntu is probably redundant. The Python Alpine one should be sufficient as it uses Alpine internally.

I had a similar issue not with `apk` but with `apt-get`.

```
FROM node:14

FROM jekyll/jekyll

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
  sqlite
```

Error:

```
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
```

If I change the order, then it works.

```
FROM node:14

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
  sqlite

FROM jekyll/jekyll
```

Note, as in first link I added above, multiple FROMs might removed from Docker as a feature.