# MultiStage dockerfile skips first step and only runs second one

Tags: docker, dockerfile, python-3.7, google-cloud-sdk

Docker file that's supposed to install cloud sdk and python 3.7 is skipping the cloud sdk and only running the python3.7 step.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:247.0.0

FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /test
COPY . .
RUN python3 -m pip install -U pip
```

- build image: `docker build -t test -t test .`
  check python3.7 installation: `docker run test python3 --version` .
  output: `Python 3.7.9`
- check gcloudsdk installation: `docker run test gcloud version`. output:  `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"gcloud\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled`

Comment: It doesn't look like you do anything in the first stage.  What result are you expecting?

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to install cloudsdk then install python3.7.

Comment: This multiple-`FROM` syntax creates two separate images; see for example [Multiple FROMs - what it means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322103/multiple-froms-what-it-means).  There's no way to combine two images.  I'd suggest starting `FROM python` and then installing the Google Cloud SDK separately.

Answer (score 0):

An answer from David Maze:

This multiple-FROM syntax creates two separate images; see for example Multiple FROMs - what it means. There's no way to combine two images. I'd suggest starting FROM python and then installing the Google Cloud SDK separately.